# Unity3d - Call public static variable performance

Tags: c#, performance, variables, unity-game-engine, static

I want to know if I call a public static variable from another script in Update or FixedUpdate function , is that affect on performance ?

something like :

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class CC : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Components
    public static Rigidbody rigidbodys;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbodys = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rigidbodys.freezeRotation = true;
        rigidbodys.useGravity = false;
        rigidbodys.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

And in another script :

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
      if(CC.rigidbodys.velocity > 1)
          {
            DoSomething();
          }
}
```

If I use this way, will reduce performance or not?

Comment: Not related o the question, but I don't think you want rigidbodys member to be static.  CC is a monobehavior, potentially attached to many different gameobjects,  **each with thier OWN rigid body**.  Static modifier means ALL the CC instances will share the same single rigidbody reference.   [If CC is meant to be a singleton (meaning ONLY one will be in the scene), it probablay wouldn't matter though.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks very good. 
In your Fixed Update you only access the rigibody (which is set once in awake) and this is cheap.
You can also make a normal **public Rigidbody rigbdy** and pass your configured gameobject in the inspector. Then you can pass the content to your static Rigidbody. So you clean up the Awake.

```js
    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbodys = ridbdy;
    }
```

From perfromance side (> means better):
static > Singleton Pattern > GetComponent/FindObject

Comment: Thank's but my question is in part two.  when I call that static `rigidbody` in another script. i want to know is this a good way ? or not ?

Comment: I know and it is a good way. Better than Singletone Pattern in performance, which is another way to get a Rigidbody from another class and to make sure that there is only one instance. You have the possibility to have many CC intances in your game and all write into the same static rigidbody.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep you getComponent() out of update(), it would be faster than, for example, calculating the velocity in the other script.

Comment: It is a public static , not just a public variable !     public  static variables do not need `getcomponent()`.

Comment: yes, you’re right. But what i meant was the rigid body.

Comment: getComponent() is the slowest part of your code, so it is good that it’s placed in awake. If you only need the checking once during fixed update, then the codes provided are fine; if the condition is needed more than once within a frame, you can consider storing it in a local variable, like isMoving = rigidBody.velocity > 0.0f.

Comment: Thank's but my question is in part two.  when I call that static `rigidbody` in another script. i want to know is this a good way ? or not ? @BorisLi

Comment: I can't think of any better alternatives for your situation, therefore, I'd say it's a good way.